# why do you need 10 rep to post an image?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I see new users unable to post a picture for identification because they only have one reputation like [this](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/5273/need-to-identify-this-plant-please) and [this](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/5261/do-i-have-a-totem-plant)

This makes the question difficult to answer and frustrates the user. I realize this is likely to be be some extremely clever anti spam thing but it works against new users.

Can this be tweaked?  For example:

questions tagged "identification" do not require reputation to post a picture
or
identification tags get more instructions on how to post at imgur

Comment: I like the idea in theory. Not sure if it's viable in practice

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of September 5th, new users (those with less than 10 rep) can [add images directly to their posts on most sites across the SE network](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/195927/146318). See here for details: [Announcement: new users can now post images](https://gardening.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/479/announcement-new-users-can-now-post-images)

Answer (score 2):

I think this might be helpful if it can be policed adequately. Also low rep users are welcome to upload their images to another site and link them in their question.

Also, we really should start closing ID questions with no pictures. they aren't really helpful to anyone and can easily be reopened when they are edited with pictures.

Comment: asking users to upload pictures to another site or closing identification questions without pictures and asking them to come back when they have the rep is just one more step that turns people away.  We need to make it easy...