# Announcement: new users can now post images

Tags: discussion

Since the beginning of Stack Exchange, new users—those with less than 10 rep—have not been allowed to add images to their posts. Since this can be a deterrent for them, other users on several sites, including [here on Gardening & Landscaping](https://gardening.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/421/why-do-you-need-10-rep-to-post-an-image) have asked for this restriction to be removed. Earlier this month, [Stack Exchange lifted the restriction](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/195927/146318), so new users can add photos directly to their posts.

### What does this mean?

1. If you see a post from a new user that **would benefit from** a photograph, ask them in a comment to add one and direct them to the image control above the editor (or the <kbd>Ctrl-G</kbd> keyboard shortcut for the same). (Previously, you'd have had to ask them to upload it somewhere, post a link and wait for a higher-rep user to edit it into the post).
2. If a question **needs** a photograph, like an [identification](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identification) question that doesn't provide enough detail in the text to be answerable, in addition to the comment as above, also vote or flag to close the question. I [suggested wording for the close reason](https://gardening.meta.stackexchange.com/a/453/26); please feel free to improve on it.
3. If you see this privilege being abused (users posting spam, etc.), please flag it and the moderators will take care of it as soon as possible.

---

**tl;dr** New users (those with less than 10 rep) can now add images directly to their posts. Where it's appropriate, please help them by leaving comments asking them to do so, and telling them how.

Comment: Excellent, thanks to the team for requesting this as it will prevent some frustration by first time users.