# Do people who provide questions get notifications that we need more information?

Tags: feature-request

There are so many good questions that we eventually have to close as there is no more response from the original asker. Do they get notifications when we comment on their questions?  At the very least the 4 or 5 reasons we have don't address that communication has ceased, and without getting more information from the asker, we have to close the question...and we lose a 'client'?

Can we get rid of the restrictions to post pictures and at least include a better guide for brand new askers?

Comment: See related questions: [1](http://meta.gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/135/how-to-ask-plant-identification-questions), [2](http://meta.gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/501/how-can-we-improve-quality-in-the-identification-tag).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, when a comment is posted requesting more information (or anything else), it will go into their inbox. Many people, however, seem to post a question and then abandon it, in which case the OP probably won't come back anyway.

[The restrictions regarding new users posting pictures have been removed](https://gardening.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/479/announcement-new-users-can-now-post-images), so basically, it is up to the new user not to abandon the question.

See [this](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/13348/will-grass-seeding-on-an-existing-lawn-help-prevent-control-weed-grasses) question, where the OP actually deleted their account within an hour of posting. I will never know why people will do that, or even abandon their question, but there isn't really anything we can do about it.